# How to add a simple user roles - ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET MVC, and I've been looking at a lot of different ways of adding User Roles
for my ASP.NET MVC site. I want to use the users' database(s) that are automatically made for you when you make a new ASP.NET MVC project.

That contain the tables:

- AspNetRoles
- AspNetUserClaims
- AspNetUserLogins
- AspNetUserRoles
- AspNetUsers

I've been looking at a few tutorials and it's a bit of a minefield for beginners I think.

All I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Return View();
}
```

So users with the role administrator can access the index page.

Comment: do you want to add roles using UI? or would you mind using simple sql script to do that and assign those roles while registering users?

Comment: Plenty of documentation on roles based available in google.  There's quite a bit more to it than you've included.  Why not give one of those guides a try and let us know if you get stuck rather than asking us to do it for you.  The main purpose of my post is to introduce an alternative however: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/01/leveraging-claims-based-security-in-aspnet-45.aspx

Comment: @DSR Id like to users with the role admin to add the roles to other users using ui

Comment: It would be hard to find a time write all the code here. There are number of sample projects and examples available for asp.net identity.

Comment: @sakir: NO. Absolutely not. There is no reason to subclass `AuthorizeAttribute` for something like this.

Comment: If you want a simple GUI to manage your Identity users, then Scott Hanselman has a [nice blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx) describing Thinktecture.IdentityManager.

Comment: This is the best article I've found so far: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The first step is to create the `admin` role. This is easy enough:

```
context.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "admin" });
context.SaveChanges();
```

To add the role to an existing user:

```
var role = context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "admin");
user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = role.Id });
```

Both of these steps can and should be handled in your `Seed` method of `Migrations\Configuration.cs`, along with creating any initial users that should be administrators.

For the ability of administrators to add roles to other users, you've got the first step covered already: protect the action with `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]`.

Next, you'll need a view model to work with your user. Something like the following:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    // User properties you'd like to edit goes here

    public List<int> SelectedRoleIds { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleChoices { get; set; }
}
```

You'll need to map your `ApplicationUser` to/from this view model. Then, you'll need to manually populate the two role properties in `UserViewModel`:

`RoleChoices` should be an enumerable of all available roles:

```
model.RoleChoices = context.Roles.Select(m => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = m.Id,
    Text = m.Name
});
```

`SelectedRoleIds` should be a list of the ids of all roles currently assigned to the user:

```
model.SelectedRoleIds = user.Roles.Select(m => m.RoleId);
```

In your view, then, you'll construct your multiselect:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedRoleIds, Model.RoleChoices)
```

When creating a new user, you can simply set the user's roles directly on post:

```
user.Roles = model.SelectedRoleIds.Select(m => new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = m });
```

When editing an existing user, greater care has to be taken, since you'll get integrity errors if you save the same role id twice for the same user. First, you'll need to remove any roles that have been deselected:

```
user.Roles.Where(m => !model.SelectedRoleIds.Contains(m.RoleId))
    .ToList().ForEach(role => user.Roles.Remove(role));
```

Then, you'll need to add any newly selected roles:

```
var existingUserRoles = user.Roles.Select(m => m.RoleId);
model.SelectedRoleIds.Except(existingUserRoles)
    .ToList().ForEach(roleId => user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole
    {
        RoleId = roleId
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time for this, i will try this now :D