# Role-based Authorization without login

Tags: .net, owin, roles

I'm developing a public API that doesn't have a UI.

Some context: When a new user makes a request, they're added to the database with an initial role of 'Standard'. And although it's inefficient, any Admin users are modified to be that Role by manually updating the record in the database.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
      public async Task ExampleFunction(RequestModel model)
      {
         // do stuff
      }
}
```

However, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.0) and the results I've found through searching all suggest that a login view is necessary, where the users Identity is checked and then they're provided with an auth token for any subsequent requests.

Is there a way to utilise the 'Authorize' attribute without having to generate an auth token, and instead validate the users Role against their record in a database? i.e.

```
User Record
  Id - 2121
  Name - Example Name
  Role(s) - Admin (check the role in the 'Authorize' attribute matches this value)
```

Currently, these Role checks are made inside of the controllers functions i.e.

```
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
      public async Task ExampleFunction(RequestModel model)
      {
         if(!await userService.isUserAdmin(model.UserId)){
             // user is not admin 
             // do stuff
         }
         // user is admin
         // do stuff
      }
}
```

My research so far is suggesting what I'm trying to achieve is not possible, and if that's the case then that's ok, I just haven't managed to find a definitive answer and was hoping someone here would be able to.

Comment: How do you plan on knowing which record is theirs?  Are they going to give you an id?  Username and password on every request?  Tin foil hat method?

Comment: @Becuzz See the current implementation I provided above: each request contains basic user info; userId, userName etc...

Comment: Have you looked at this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281940/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281940/)

Comment: That actually looks about right, thanks for digging that out for me (clearly my searching wasn't as extensive as I thought), much appreciated!